# Optimize a simple JOIN or IN query

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, 
                label 
FROM   bbproduct_cust 
WHERE  CUSTNO IN (SELECT CUSTNO 
                  FROM   customer 
                  WHERE  SLSRPTGRP = '1996') 
       AND DEPTNO = '0' 
ORDER  BY label ASC
```

`EXPLAIN` shows

```
id  select_type         table           type  possible_keys          key            key_len  ref    rows   Extra                                         
1   PRIMARY             bbproduct_cust  ALL   ind_deptno                                            91834  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  customer        ref   PRIMARY,ind_slsrptgrp  ind_slsrptgrp  3        const  4      Using where
```

it takes 2-3 seconds, and I need it optimized.

What options I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an *INNER JOIN*, rather than an *IN* select

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, 
                label 
FROM   bbproduct_cust INNER JOIN
        customer ON  bbproduct_cust.CUSTNO = customer.CUSTNO
WHERE  SLSRPTGRP = '1996'
       AND DEPTNO = '0' 
ORDER  BY label ASC
```

Comment: Then it would seem that you do not have the correct index on table *bbproduct_cust*

Answer (score 0):

Use an INDEX to improve performance. [Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for more details.